# Is this question really opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

[Why is base128 not used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6008047/3990767)

This question was previously closed for being primarily opinion-based, because it asks "why do people prefer base64 over base128". The question is indeed worded as if it is asking for opinions.

But apparently, the OP wouldn't expect "Because 64 is more shorter to type than 128" or some even barely controversial arguments. Most of the answers (at least the top ones) are actually professional and explain about the technical issues of implementing base128.

In fact, base128 simply doesn't exist. There is not a question of choice, but a question of impossibility.

As a result, I edited the question to make it sound a bit less opinion-based, and changed from asking about common practices to asking about existence. (This completely aligns with both the author's likely intent and the existing answers)

This question has some value in its discussion about the availability of the ASCII standard and the 128-255 bytes in charsets.

Is it appropriate to reopen this question?

Comment: is there something missing from the existing answers that requires new ones?

Comment: No, but I find the flag wrong in itself. I don't see the question developing any symptoms that a opinion-based question would develop.

Comment: The question was reopened. I totally agree to you.

Comment: And closed again (this time through a binding moderator vote) ...

Comment: Related: [Is it subjective to ask about why something wasn't implemented in the language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293815/is-it-subjective-to-ask-about-why-something-wasnt-implemented-in-the-language/)

Comment: It is not a choice whether not to do it. It is a technical impossibility. It has no controversy. base64 is a serialization standard with well-defined requirements, not a language with random rationales that the developers want. If I wanted to ask "why is base128 not possible to implement", it is an exact duplicate of this question yet totally not opinion-based. Therefore I suggest editing it rather than closing it.

Comment: Considering implementations exist; I’d say “technical impossibility” might be too much.

Comment: Based on this discussion, I suppose "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad" might be more appropriate flags for this question since "when is base64 more appropriate than base128" is the true precise question that everyone is answering. But it's hilarious to flag the question as too broad or unclear when there are several high quality answers that address the most likely question that visitors would be interested in seeing.

Comment: The question has a historical lock now.

Comment: @Zoe It is quite rude for a mod to step in like that while there is a discussion going on.

Comment: @ayhan quite the opposite. They locked the question so the discussion can continue without a voting war being waged on the question.

Comment: @yivi No. There is another type of lock for that. This is a historical lock and has nothing to do with it. This is permanent and is a final say.

Comment: You can get angry if you want. But it makes sense to lock the question until some semblance of consensus is reached. It can always be unlocked afterwards, if necessary. Right now it doesn’t need to be.

Comment: I agree with the moderator that this question should have a historical lock. It is indeed a badly written question; as I have mentioned in the comment above, it isn't really well defined. I just disagree with the choice of "opinion-based" over "too broad". And the answers are exactly high quality, which is why it's a historical lock rather than deletion.

Comment: If “closed by the wrong reason, but still closable”, it’s not worth reopening anyway.

Comment: Yes, I realized the other problem after posting this question.

Comment: @yivi There are temporary locks (like the ones used in edit wars and close-open vote wars - exactly for the reasons you mentioned) and there are permanent locks like this one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) summarizes it quite well. This happened before and similar objections were raised before. I just don't think assuming the mod doesn't know which type of lock to use will get us anywhere.

Comment: Fun fact: neither opinion-based/offtopic answers nor edit/vote wars happened in the question (before it was locked), and it's locked. And now there seems to be an even worse war in these comments.

Comment: It received 5 reopen votes and it was getting close votes when Yvette intervened. I don’t know what “war” you see on comments. I’m fine with disagreement.

Answer (score 13):

Oh boy, [here we go again.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384380/1079354)  I'm just both relieved and slightly crestfallen that we don't have someone who worked on the original transmission protocols explaining what choices they made at the time.

For the sake of brevity I'll be dramatically less thorough, but the question actually starts with a false pretense.

Base64 is *not* how binary data is *transmitted*.  Base64 is how binary data is *encoded*.  The data is still transmitted in binary, and we use an encoding format to represent it in some way to ourselves, or to make working with the binary blob easier, or sometimes both.  Both the original question and its subsequent edits only deal with transmission, which is a fact that pretty much *every* answer missed.

<sup>So...what value is in highly misinformed answers to a question?  SME's can't fix this since there's a historical lock there.</sup>

So why wouldn't it be fair game to encode it in something else?  It actually *would* be, but that's an implementation detail.  You can encode your binary data in whatever form you wish, and so long as the recipient on the other side understands that encoding, then you're good to go.

The fact that it's an implementation detail makes it too broad.  Genuinely, you can choose how to implement whatever you want however you want, but why someone made that choice over another requires talking to that *someone*, and that *someone* isn't <s>generally</s> on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is opinion based.

Who can possibly answer why base128 is not used (or even why the standard doesn't exist)?

- Members of the base128 Change Advisory Board or Design Committee?
- Members of the Steering committee that decided to not have a base128 Change Advisory Board?
- The analyst that did a consultation among the largest vendors to see if there was a need for base128?
- The CTO's of vendors that didn't implement base128? (Except [MapleSoft](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=147458) that is)

The answers would all be anecdotal. The answers provided are all explaining why such encoding scheme is not beneficial. None of the answers is authoritative. The question is opinion based and the answers confirm that.

As that question went over so many attempts to re-open it and that all failed the community has had their say many times. I don't mind it being on the site, as it has high views and reasonable answers that clear-out why base128 isn't a thing. Don't expect me (or suggest anyone else) to go on a delete rampage for that particular question. It doesn't need (and until proven otherwise) that single missing authoritative answer. It is fine with its historical lock now, given the meta attention it suddenly got. Let it gather views.

Comment: "None of the answers is authoritative" kinda funny, because if some of those people happens to answer that question, suddenly it becomes a good question... which is why question quality/topicness should be evaluated independently of the existence of answers.

Comment: Maybe if the question remains open it can receive an authorative answer some day...

Comment: Consider this reformulation of the question: "Given that base128 is a denser encoding than the ubiquitous base64, does base64 have any advantages that might justify using it to transmit binary data on the web instead of base128?". Would that still be opinion-based?

Comment: @duplode it would be an awesome question for cstheory.se or compsci.se. It would no longer be opinion based but it hardly fits the practical software development issues that are on-topic on SO. If you so desperately want to make that question fly, throw out the base128 as that is not a thing. We don't answer dreams here. Replace it with base85 but that does change the nature of the question.

Comment: "We don't answer dreams here" is a bit exaggerated. It's a very practical question, and at least more on-topic for Stackoverflow than lots of questions out there that aren't closed. But this is turning into a pure argument about correct use of question terms and hedging. This isn't something stackoverflow requires.

Comment: @SOFe if it was so much on-topic then the other attempts at re-opening it would have succeeded. The question isn't a practical development issue that software engineers will face one day or the other. If they do they probably stumbled on base128 due to this meta question. Don't get me exaggerated on how much unneeded attention that question now got.

Comment: @rene Nah, I'm not desperate enough to be bothered by the close-and-lock compromise. In any case, I quite like the final paragraph you have added to this answer.

Answer (score -14):

No, this question is not opinion-based.

The real answer is that using all the 128 ASCII character codes would also include a lot of codes commonly used for terminal control sequences. For example, the ascii code 7 rings a bell, or the ascii code 14 is the escape. This encoding should encode a binary stream into a text. Thus, it needs to have only clear textual character codes in its output. Thus we can't use the ascii codes below 32 for that. It would not be better than using the binary stream, without any encoding.

ASCII-7 contains only "real" characters between 32 and 127, what means that the 6-bit coding used by mime or uuencode is a fair compromise (it could have been optimized to use a log_96 encoding, it had not worth the price).

Roughly this is what the first, most upvoted and accepted answer says.

What we all can see, it is an objective and clear answer.

There was no competent reason to close this question. Fortunately, with the mod lock, now it at least can't be deleted, thus the googlers of the future will be able to get here the answer to this interesting question. (Although I would be more happy if I could upvote this, and its good answers, what is now impossible due to the mod lock.)

A possible reason of the close votes were imho either incompetence or hostility. Alternatively, I can also imagine that the close voters imagined the - at least, theoretical - possibility of some other reason, and they thought we can't decide, which one was the truth. However, the top tag list of the close-voters makes this option unlikely.<sup>*</sup>

"Why" questions have always an above average chance to be closed as opinion-based; "How" questions look much better in this sense.

<sup>*</sup><sub>A possible fix of similar problems would be, if the 3k+ users could take part in close/reopen decisions only in their most active tags.</sub>

---

P.s. the currently most upvoted answer to your question refers committees, what makes clear that there is no reason to believe it - in the IT world, committees are infamous from their incompetence. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) can you read more about the phenomenon.