# Is question on language design choice an opinion-based question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I had a review audit for `First Posts` for this question, [Why does the main function in Haskell not have any parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66393690/why-does-the-main-function-in-haskell-not-have-any-parameters)

When I looked at the question being asked it looked like less of debug and more of discussion to me and that it couldn't be answered with fact-based answers.

However, I failed the audit and it's, in fact, a well-received question. When I went through the answers it portrayed opinions and described the design choice of the language. A similar question I believe is answered here, [Is this question really opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387159/is-this-question-really-opinion-based). This case also falls in the second category described in this answer, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253111/3694381.

My question is what draws the line between design-choice questions vs `opinion-based` questions so that I can flag/review questions better in the future?

Edit:
I don't have issue with the fact that I failed the audit. That's okay. I want to know how to handle such questions in general or vaguely. Should I flag them as opinion-based or accept it or recommend to be moved to another SE site?

What specific parameters I can look into when deciding between acceptable language design choice questions vs opinion-based questions?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323334) and its dupe [Is it subjective to ask about why something wasn't implemented in the language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293815) also [Eric Lippert's article on questions about language design/implementation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods)

Comment: well... It is a judgement call, frankly. The post you failed the audit on can be reasoned about - there are tangible reasons why would a function accept a certain number of parameters. The second one you linked asks a potential answerer to *speculate* about the reasons why base128 is not used (and also makes an assumption that it isn't). Thankfully, de facto the answers are *mostly* talking about the advantages and disadvantages of the encoding, but that does not mean the question itself is not opinion-based (although I will leave it to SMEs to decide).

Comment: and, despite what is said above, it does smell a bit like an opinion-based question after a more thorough examination (especially when answers boil down to "who knows"), so this may be the case where it would make sense to close  and remove from the audit (or reevaluate the audit)

Comment: My questions gets answered by the similar questions @VLAZ shared. I will flag the question accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, good dupe. But still... there is the issue of audits even though you yourself are not interested in that aspect of it. Opinionated questions (or those which read opinionated) can go any way really so there is no way to, if you are looking at an audit, to have any kind of guarantee that you are going to make the choice others dictate you to make even when you have the soundest of reasoning and you pay immaculate attention to detail. "It depends" way too much. So when faced with such a question in review, always look at it outside of the review queue to catch ninja audits.