# This question doesn't seem opinionated

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69134602/6789816) in question.

The asker is relatively new to the site (3 months, 23 reputation). They made the unfortunate mistake of beginning their question with *"Looking for some opinion."*.

I thought for sure that this was an easy close but, after reading it, I changed my mind; I think the question is appropriately formatted for this site and we should consider reopening it. It is asking the following two questions (about C#):

- `ref struct` exists, why not `ref delegate`?
- Does something exist that already accomplishes this?

Despite their comment, *"Looking for some opinion."*, this post asks a couple of good questions (yes, the first one is a bit subjective, but I think it qualifies as constructive). As far as I can tell, this question has not been asked before on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's a hypothetical design question about an existing language. Not sure exactly how it can be answered concretely.

Comment: I mean, edit it if you think it's not asking for an opinion, despite it literally asking for an opinion. Both the title, and all references to whether x makes sense, would need to be replaced with more actionable questions.

Comment: @VLAZ, might there be a concrete reason `ref delegate` does not exist? A constraint of the language? Or maybe it's just nonsense? There are possible answers that require facts and citations, not whimsical _"nah, I don't like that"_. And the second part is easily answered with _"Yeah, you can do **B**"_. It totally can be answered concretely.

Comment: @ConnorLow "the second part" is also a problem. One question per question, please.

Comment: @ConnorLow as for asking about why a language is as it is, please check what Eric Lippert's answers to [Is asking "why" on language specifications still considered as "primarily opinion-based" if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382) and [Is it subjective to ask about why something wasn't implemented in the language?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819)

Comment: I can peel apples and eat the apple peel. Certainly I can peel a pineapple and eat the pineapple peel?

Comment: Note that the question wasn't closed for being opinionated (even though it is, for reasons others have already explained), it was closed for not being focused enough, which would require a much more fundamental change to the question even if it was edited to not ask for opinions, for reasons Eric explains in the links a few comments above.

Answer (score 21):

Considering that at the moment of posting this, the question starts with the very words:

> Looking for some opinion.

And that what I can parse as the main question is:

> does the concept of ref delegates make sense?

I would say that yes, this is absolutely an opinionated question, asking for opinions about if something "makes sense".

Making sense is absolutely, without any doubt, a profoundly subjective matter, and only opinions can be had about if something "makes sense".